# MySql how to format output rows to single lines?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to format my MySQL results to one line rather than rows. Here is what my results look like

```
select name, picks from week1:

Name          Picks              
----        ---------------
Nick Smith   New York Giants       
Nick Smith   Dallas Cowboys        
Nick Smith   Carolina Panthers    
Nick Smith   Philadelphia Eagles     
Frank Ann    New York Giants       
Frank Ann    New York Jets         
Frank Ann    Carolina Panthers     
Frank Ann    Buffalo Bills         
.
.
Etc
```

I am trying to format the MySQL results to display as:

```
Nick Smith   New York Giants, Dallas Cowboys, Carolina Panthers, Philadelphia
Frank Ann    New York Giants, New York Jets, Carolina Panthers, Buffalo Bills
....
...
Etc




WRAP OFF
```

Won't work because the Picks for that specific person will show as a row

Any Idea's how this could be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(picks SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM week1 GROUP BY name;

Comment: Use this: SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Picks SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Table GROUP BY Name